# How to dynamically add a unique id to a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically adding radio buttons to html through js. I need to add unique id's to the radio buttons so I can access the value selected.
How do I do it?

here is the js code.

```
 function createMyElements(standardAddress,k){
            return [
                    '<input type="radio" id=',"selectedAddress[k]",' name="addressField"  value=>', standardAddress[k],'<br>',
        ].join('\n');
        }
```

where selectedAddress is an array with some constants to identify the radio button selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the method to

```
 function createMyElements(standardAddress,k){
            return [
                    '<input type="radio" id=',"selectedAddress["+k+"]",' name="addressField"  value=>', standardAddress[k],'<br>',
        ].join('\n');
        }
```

`"selectedAddress[k]"` is changed to `"selectedAddress["+k+"]"` to append the value of `k` to the `"selectedAddress"`